# How to use CSSStyleSheet.insertRule() to change a :root property

Tags: javascript, html, css, url

I am trying to set the background color of the :root css property in my html file based off a hash in the url.
The attached code works, but the hash doesn't persist through page changes on the site. I'm thinking that I can use CSSStyleSheet.insertRule() to make the css change persist since each page uses the same stylesheet, but I'm not sure how to properly use the function.

```
<script>
      if (window.location.hash) {
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
          '--main-bg-color',
          window.location.hash
        )
      }
</script>
```

Comment: were you ever able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This sort of works for me. I don't know if it will work in all browsers, I only tried chrome and firefox:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
:root { --main-bg-color: red }
body { background-color : var(--main-bg-color) }
</style>
<script>
  if (window.location.hash) {
    let hashValue = window.location.hash;
    let tagName = '--main-bg-color';
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty( tagName, hashValue);
    let newRule = ':root { ' + tagName + ':' + window.location.hash + ';}';
    let nextRoot = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules.length ;
    alert(tagName + ': ' + hashValue + "\n" + '#' + nextRoot + '  ' + newRule);
    document.styleSheets[0].insertRule (newRule, nextRoot)
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    this should turn the background color from red to whatever value is in the hash.
</body>
</html>
```

i believe the solution (for now) is to insert a new rule, but make sure the new rule has the highest priority number.  you could also determine the current `:root` value, parse it out, and make changes there as well.

I have not seen any javascript calls to manipulate CSS rules except for `insertRule` and `removeRule`, or if something like that exists, I missed them. I did look through `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0]` and all I could find was `cssText`.

Comment: so the only way to replace an existing rule w/ this API is to insert one that takes priority over it (using insertRule), and then to delete the old rule. This sounded simple enough! until i tried it... i was wrong, lol. there are all kinds of complications. The biggest one is that its important to ensure that the deletion of the 'old' rule doesn't happen until the new one has been applied. Which means deferring it to, at the very least, the next animation frame. Which makes the already annoying problem of tracking numerical indices even more of a headache, bc now its asynchronous. Wheeeee